# How to reset a fragment's view?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

If I have a fragment where I dynamically set a view with onCreateView(), how would I go about calling it again?

I want to implement some kind of "refresh" where the view changes based on the JSON response. I tried making a new function that does midnightSV.removeAllViews(), but how can I call onCreateView() again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't without detaching and re-attaching the fragment.

If you just want to update the data in the view, you can find those views and refresh them from the existing fragment.

If you really want multiple sets of *unique layouts*, you can look into using a `ViewFlipper` for your fragment layout and then call [setDisplayedChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild%28int%29) to switch to a specific view.